# Is $(\mathbb Q^+, . )$ isomorphic with a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ ?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

Does there exist any injective group homomorphism from $(\mathbb Q^+,.)$ ( the multiplicative group of positive rational numbers ) to $(\mathbb R,+)$ ? I know that $(\mathbb Q^+,.) \cong (\mathbb Z[x] , +)$ but I am still getting no idea ... I have tried like checking divisibility , essential subgroups , elements of finite order ... Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: What about an isomorphism to (Q,+)? They are order isomorphic and their operations are increasing in each element. This seems sufficient.

Comment: No, $(Q,+)$ is divisible, while $(Q^+,\cdot)$ is not.

Comment: @KeithKearnes What is divisibility in this context?

Comment: @Alephnull : https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj26eiEx8fOAhWBvY8KHTlUCdkQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDivisible_group&usg=AFQjCNEbIJpfTTDhVIZ80AVKchm5jjfdMA

Comment: @SaunDev oh yes, i see that now. I hope my stupid ideas are somehow helpful (un my defense i only think very briefly before posting)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to try 
$$ x\mapsto \ln x$$

Comment: Another contender for the 'shortest answer trophy'. You may want to omit 'You may want to try', though ;)

Comment: The body of an answer must be at least 30 characters.  And putting in "invisible" stuff to minimize your answer is cheating.

Answer (score 4):

The subgroup $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ (with respect to addition) is a free abelian group over a countable basis. So it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}^+,\cdot)$. Any transcendental number instead of $\pi$ is good as well.

Alternatively, $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^{(\mathfrak{c})}$ (direct sum of $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$ copies of $\mathbb{Q}$) and it's easy to embed in it a free abelian group over a countable basis.

<sub>Of course, using the logarithm is way easier.</sub>